# Mutliple independantly sortable lists on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple galleries on my page and want each to be sortable. The pictures should stay in each gallery.

```
<div class="sortable">
  <img src="foo.jpg" id="item-1">
  <img src="foo2.jpg" id="item-2">
  <img src="foo3.jpg" id="item-3">
</div>
<div class="sortable">
  <img src="foo_1.jpg" id="item-1">
  <img src="foo_12.jpg" id="item-2">
  <img src="foo_13.jpg" id="item-3">
</div>
<div class="sortable">
  <img src="bar.jpg" id="item-1">
  <img src="bar2.jpg" id="item-2">
  <img src="bar3.jpg" id="item-3">
</div>
<div class="sortable">
  <img src="bar_1.jpg" id="item-1">
  <img src="bar_12.jpg" id="item-2">
  <img src="bar_13.jpg" id="item-3">
</div>
```

I must confess I'm not pretty good at JQuery. I tried to "solve" this problem as follows:

```
$(".sortable").each(function() {
    $(this).sortable({
        update:function(event, ui) {
            var postData = $(this).sortable("serialize");
            //Code to post to PHP and insert into DB here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the classes, but give every `div` an ID, then, go here to see for the jQuery: [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)